# Apache Camel Event Store

Tags: apache-camel, cqrs, jbossfuse, event-sourcing

I have a JBoss Fuse project, where I receive data (entities) from an external source and process it. I would like to implement event sourcing to be able to simulate the data consumption afterwards.

Is there a possibility to include some kind of event sourcing in camel routes? Is there a certain event store, which works best with camel and can be easily integrated?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards, Sandra

Answer (score 1):

[akka-persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/persistence.html) is one such implementation of event sourcing. It can be integrated with a Camel route relatively easily:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/camel.html#akka-camel-components

akka-persistence supports a number of pluggable storage backends, including  cassandra, jdbc, redis, just to name a few popular options.